# T-SQL Campos en tabla a distintas columnas

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando hacer un query con una tabla con un formato que no sé como extraer.
Mi tabla tiene este formato.

| Codigo | Producto | Valor Atributo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Codigo_Atributo_1 | Codigo_Producto_1 | 1.1 |
| Codigo_Atributo_2 | Codigo_Producto_1 | 0.9 |

Estoy intentando obtener un query con un formato como el siguiente

| Codigo Producto | Valor Atributo 1 | Valor Atributo 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Codigo_Producto | 1.1 | 0.9 |

Intenté con

```
SELECT t1.Codigo_Producto, 
CASE WHEN t2.Codigo = Codigo_Atributo_2 
THEN Codigo_Atributo_2
```

Pero obtengo todos los `t1.Codigo_Producto` duplicados.
Alguna ayuda para lidiar con esto?
Saludos!

Comment: Intentaste usar GROUP BY Codigo_Producto?

Comment: Tienes dos tablas t1 y t2, que no estás relacionando de ninguna forma, y estás haciendo un case sobre un campo de t2? Eso no va a salir bien, no sé qué haga MSSQL ahí pero tiene pinta de hacer NATURAL JOIN

Comment: @Gervera Efectivamente estaba usando GROUP BY pero no funcionaba con esto.

Comment: @Alfabravo me faltó en el ejemplo el LEFT JOIN con que uno ambas tablas, pero si está considerado. Gracias.

Comment: Eso significa que diste un ejemplo imposible de replicar. Me alegra que encontraras la respuesta, pero claramente fue un ejercicio de adivinación por parte de quien respondió.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás tratando de hacer es una transposición de columnas, también conocido como "pivot". Existe una instrucción con ese nombre en SQL que permite hacerlo, pero prefiero hacer lo que llamo "agregado condicional". Esto me da más flexibilidad y en algunos casos da mejor rendimiento (cuando se involucra más de una columna o agregado).

El ejemplo quedaría más o menos así, pero seguramente hay que cambiar los nombres de las columnas y tabla, así como el valor usado.

```
SELECT Codigo_Producto, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Codigo_Atributo = 'Codigo_Atributo_1' THEN Valor_Atributo END) AS Valor_Atributo_1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Codigo_Atributo = 'Codigo_Atributo_2' THEN Valor_Atributo END) AS Valor_Atributo_2
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY Codigo_Producto;
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Funciona perfecto !!!!